# Display WOO Commerce products on HTML page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am wondering if anyone knows of a solution that will allow us to display certain product category pages on a static html website. Is this possible? If not, do you have any recommendations or suggestions?

Here is an example:
Category on our Woo Commmerce site:
https://birdiemedia.net/product-category/golf-event-signage/

Static (one page) website we would like to display these products:
http://teesigns.cc/

Thank you

Comment: you can provide products information with the REST API (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). and then on the html page, you can read these information with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way the question is written you want a single page website with that one page displaying all products within a single category.

Install and configure Wordpress and WooCommerce create the desired product category and add all relevant products.

Do not create any menus.

Then...

1. Go to Appearance -> Customize -> Frontpage -> Product Categories
2. Customization option of WooCommerce Category section are divided into 3 parts
   Product Categories:
   Product Category Layout:
   Product Category Color & Image:
3. Insert the section content & select the category layout
4. Click on “Save & Publish” to save your changes.

Hope this helps.

Best.

Tim